# Fractional Derivatives of Exponential Functions

Tags: calculus

I am studying the generalization/derivation if the $\alpha^{\mbox{th}}$ derivative of $e^{ax}$. I got lost in the third line. Could someone please please fill in the missing lines so that the derivation will be in detail? I really need to figure this thing out. 
With $\displaystyle D_x^n f(x)=\lim_{h\to 0}h^{-n}\sum_{m=0}^n(-1)^m{}_nC_m f(x+(n-m)h)$ where $_nC_m=\frac{n!}{m!(n-m)!}$ and with $f(x)=e^{ax}$,
\begin{array}{rcl}
\displaystyle D_x^\alpha e^{ax}&=& \lim_{h\to 0} h^{-\alpha}\sum_{n=0}^\alpha(-1)^n{}
_\alpha C_n e^{a(x+(\alpha-n)h)} \\
&=& e^{ax}\lim_{h\to 0} h^{-\alpha}\sum_{n=0}^\alpha(-1)^n{}_\alpha C_n (e^{ah})^{\alpha-n} \\
&=&  e^{ax}\lim_{h\to 0} h^{-\alpha} (e^{ah}-1)^\alpha \mbox{what happened???} \\
&=& a^\alpha e^{ax}
\end{array}

I didnt get how the third line came up from the second line. Can you plase fill in the missing details for me? Thank you.

Comment: Binomium of Newton?

Comment: @Raskolnikov Yes, but it is probably better known in the English-speaking world as the [binomial theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\alpha} \binom{\alpha}{n}(-e^{ah})^{n}=(1-e^{ah})^{\alpha}
$$

This is called Binomial theorem. In general:
$$
(a+b)^n = \sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}a^{k}b^{n-k}
$$

Answer (score 0):

The formula you used is not correct. The correct formula is the Grunwald-Letnikov derivative.
I cannot write it in this word processor. Send me a mail and I'll send you a paper with the solution.

mdo@fct.unl.pt